# How to replace DDMImpl constants?

Tags: liferay

i'm migratinga portlet modulo from liferay 7.0 to 7.4, and i need to implement some constants what was in the class DDMIMPL in the package com.liferay.dynamic.data.mapping.util.impl.DDMImpl, i replace this with com.liferay.dynamic.data.mapping.form.field.type.constants.DDMFormFieldTypeConstants and I managed to get some of the constants I need, then I added com.liferay.dynamic.data.mapping.internal.util.DDMImpl but I still need to get DDMImpl.TYPE_DDM_LINK_TO_PAGE, where can I get it from? some idea?

Answer (score 0):

`grep -r "LINK_TO_PAGE" liferay-src/` reveals `DDMFormFieldType.LINK_TO_PAGE` from `com.liferay.dynamic.data.mapping.model`.

Though deprecated it's still in use in a couple of places in Liferay's own source code